# Como faço para forçar a entrada no "while"?

Tags: c, c++, while

Este programa permite calcular a tabuada de ate 10 até um dado número x. Mas no ciclo do `while` depois da primeira iteração ele não entra e salta para o fim. Por exemplo, se eu inserir 2 o meu *output* é:

```
Introduza o numero da tabuada que quer!

3
tabuada do 0

 0x3=0

 1x3=0

 2x3=0

 3x3=0

 4x3=0

 5x3=0

 6x3=0

 7x3=0

 8x3=0

 9x3=0

 10x3=0

 tabuada do 1


 tabuada do 2


 tabuada do 3
```

O código que gera a saída acima é o seguinte:

```
void main()
{


int i,x, a, resultado;

printf(" Introduza o numero da tabuada que quer!\n\n");

scanf("%d", &a);

i = 0;

x = 0;

do  {
    printf(" tabuada do %d\n\n", x);

{

        while (i <= 10)
        {
            resultado = i*x;
            printf(" %dx%d=%d\n", i, a, resultado);
            i++;
        }
    }

        x++;

} while (x <= a);

}
```

Comment: Você precisa voltar o `i` para `0` após imprimir a primeira tabuada.

Comment: Mas se só quer a tabuada do número digitado, não entendi o motivo de existir o loop de fora (o `do..while`)

Comment: eu quero todas as tabuadas ate o numero digitado

Comment: ja reparei o erro, obrigado :)

Comment: O problema é que você está considerando a posição da tabuada como ponto de partida do seu cálculo, e não o tipo da tabuada que pretende  realizar o cálculo. Desta forma sempre que escolher uma delas ele irá continuar o loop a partir desta posição até o final.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você não está reiniciando o contador da tabuada cada vez que troca de número. Aproveitei para dar uma organizada no código. Tem alguns erros conceituais sobre a tabuada que eu aproveitei para resolver.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {    
    int i = 1, x = 1, a, resultado;
    printf(" Introduza a quantidade de tabuadas que quer! ");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    do  {
        printf("\nTabuada do %d\n", x);
        while (i <= 10) {
            resultado = i*x;
            printf(" %dx%d=%d\n", i, a, resultado);
            i++;
        }
        i = 1; // <============ seu problema estava aqui.
        x++;
    } while (x <= a);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/6zovRc). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/pjjmmqaw-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/ResetLoop.c).

Answer (score 4):

Basta resetar o contador `i`, pois ele é o controle de sua tabuada.

Após o while mude para:

```
i = 0;
```

Ficando assim:

```
void main()
{
int i,x, a, resultado;

printf(" Introduza o numero da tabuada que quer!\n\n");

scanf("%d", &a);

i = 0;

x = 0;

do  {
    printf(" tabuada do %d\n\n", x);
    {
        while (i <= 10)
        {
            resultado = i*x;
            printf(" %dx%d=%d\n", i, a, resultado);
            i++;
        }
        i = 0;
    }
    x++;
} while (x <= a);
}
```